# Im trying to count down to zero from a positive then count up from zero using a negative number

Tags: c

Count up from a negative and down from a positive not sure how to do this when i enter a negative variable my screen goes haywire

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x=10;
    printf("Enter a value:");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while(x)
    {
        printf(" %d",x);
        x--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check `scanf()` return value, don't ignore functions return values.

Comment: You are decrementing the value regardless of its sign value. So a negative number will only become smaller and never reach 0 until overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Use `x--` if `x` is positive and `x++` if `x` is negative.

```
if ( x > 0 )
  x--;
else
  x++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `x` negative, it will never reach zero (well, just at overflow) since in every iteration it is decremented, so your `while` loop will never terminate (it is looping while is not zero).